# Transformation of csv to json in Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The below is my transformation part from csv to json. The csv has three columns.

```
class ConvertCsvToJson(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        # Assuming the CSV has three columns: col1, col2, col3
        col1, col2, col3 = element.split(',')
        
        # Create a JSON object
        json_obj = {
            'col1': col1.strip(),
            'col2': col2.strip(),
            'col3': col3.strip()
        }
        
        yield json_obj
```

and the pipeline code as

```
(pipeline
        | 'Read CSV' >> ReadFromText(input_file, skip_header_lines=1)  # Skip the first line
        | 'Convert to JSON' >> beam.ParDo(ConvertCsvToJson())
```

the problem is the json code is coming as below because I dont have a loop. I cant seem to figure out on the fix

```
{'col1': '100001', 'col2': 'Claude Potier (Earth-616)', 'col3': 'Secret'}
{'col1': '100002', 'col2': 'Elektra Natchios (Earth-616)', 'col3': 'Secret'}
```

it should be coming as

```
[
  {
    "col1": "100001",
    "col2": "Claude Potier (Earth-616)",
    "col3": "Secret"
  },
  {
    "col1": "100002",
    "col2": "Elektra Natchios (Earth-616)",
    "col3": "Secret"
  }
]
```

also is there a way I can generate the col1,clo2 based on the headers from the csv itself?
Also the pipeline almost takes 5 minutes to run, is there a way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Beam is for the distributed computing. So it does not know the entire data to dump everything as a big json object.
2. You can grab the headers by just reading the first line.
3. Maybe a better way to handle the json format is to use beam.dataframe:

```
import apache_beam as beam
pipeline = beam.Pipeline()

beam_df = pipeline | 'Read CSV' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('solar_events.csv')
beam.dataframe.io.to_json(beam_df, 'solar_events.jsonl') 

pipeline.run()
```

`solar_events.csv` is

```
timestamp,event
2021-03-20 09:37:00,March Equinox
2021-06-21 03:32:00,June Solstice
2021-09-22 19:21:00,September Equinox
2021-12-21 15:59:00,December Solstice
```

but the output json is

```
{"timestamp":{"0":"2021-03-20 09:37:00","1":"2021-06-21 03:32:00","2":"2021-09-22 19:21:00","3":"2021-12-21 15:59:00"},"event":{"0":"March Equinox","1":"June Solstice","2":"September Equinox","3":"December Solstice"}}
```

This allows the data can be stored distributively.
4. Dataflow has the overhead to setup the computing environment. It could take 5 minutes or even more if your python code has many dependencies.